# HOW to put onkeyup on PHP Javascript Invoice, calculating for the current and previous of the electricity readings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please Help me, I'm having a hard time with both javascript and php i need to give a receipt for a tenant by only inserting the value of the current electricity, then the current electricity will be subtracted to the previous electricity then multiply the answer to the electricity rate. I will only just fetch the values of previous and electricity rate on the database.
Here's my code for your reference..

```js
window.onload = function()

{
  var previous = $('#previous');
  var rate = $('#rate')
  var current = document.getElementById('current');
  current.onkeyup = current.onpaste = function() {

    if (this.value.length == 0) {

      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';

      return;
    }

    var number = parseInt(this.value);

    if (isNaN(number)) return;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (number - previous) * rate;
  };
  current.onkeyup();
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PRESENT</label>:

  <input class="custom-input" id="current" name="current"></input>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PREVIOUS</label>:
  <input class="custom-input" value="<?php echo $value['charges']?>" id="#previous"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">TOTAL CONSUMED</label>:
  <span class="custom-input" type="" id="" readonly></span> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">ELECTRIC RATE</label>:
  <input class="custom-input" value="<?php echo $value['elec_rate']?>" id="rate"></input>
</div>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">AMOUNT</label>:
<span value="" type="" class="custom-input" id="result" readonly></span> 
<div class="form-group">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok... now I see the new version. You stil have some issue with #previous id. It seems like an extra # in there.